# PHP form does not get sent

Tags: php, html, sql, forms

I used the code of the following [website](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Basic-Login-Authentication-with-PHP-and-MySQL.html) for giving my website the add user functionality. I used it before and it worked well. however now I have changed it and have modified it to my needs. however it doesn't seem to work. the error message i get is "please enter form correctly" which is the message I have set in case the various fields have not been sent (please refer to code pasted below). I thought it might be something that i may have messed up , so I tried the code of the website and it doesn't work . is it cause of the wamp server settings? or is it cz

1. i am checking if only the username and password along with the session form token are being?
2. after checking for only the above fields, i am adding much more information to the database -  name, emailid etc
3. my database table has more columns than the number of values I am passing.

Since I am new to php authorization and validation I can't think of anything that i can to debug. Any help will b really appreciated. I am posting my html form, and php code below. My sql table looks has the following colums : userid ,firstname, lastname, username,password, emailid, teamname, money, total, points

html form -

```
<?php
 
/*** begin our session ***/
session_start();
 
/*** set a form token ***/
$form_token = md5( uniqid('auth', true) );
 
/*** set the session form token ***/
$_SESSION['form_token'] = $form_token;
?>
 
<form class="form-inline" method="post" action="useradd.php" name="login_form">
              <p><input type="text" class="span2" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="First Name"></p>
                          <p><input type="text" class="span2" name="lastname" id="Last Name" placeholder="Last Name"></p>
                          <p><input type="text" class="span2" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username"></p>
                          <p class="help-block" style="font-size:12px"> Username should be between 4-20 characters long.</p>
              <p><input type="Password" class="span2" name="Password" placeholder="Password"></p>
                          <p class="help-block" style="font-size:12px"> Password must be between 4-20 characters long. Must be alpha-numeric</p>
                          <p><input type="Password" class="span2" name="Password" placeholder="Re-Enter Password"></p>
                          <p><input type="text" class="span4" name="emailid" id="emailid" placeholder="Emaid ID - example@example.com"></p>
                          <p><input type="text" class="span2" name="teamname" id="teamname" placeholder="Team name"></p>
                          <p class="help-block" style="font-size:12px"> Select your Unique team name.</p>
                          <p>
                  <select class="selectpicker">
                     <option>The name of the city where you were born</option>
                     <option>The name of your first pet</option>
                     <option>What is your mother's maiden name</option>
                  </select>
                </p>
                <p><input type="text" class="span2" name="secretanswer" id="secretanswer" placeholder="Secret Answer"></p>
                <p>
                                <input type="hidden" name="form_token" value="<?php echo $form_token; ?>" /><br />
              <p><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button></p>
            </form>
```

php code - file named - useradd.php

```
<?php
/*** begin our session ***/
session_start();

/*** first check that both the username, password, form token etc have been sent ***/
if(!isset( $_POST['username'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['form_token']))
{
    $message = 'work for the love of god';
}
/*** check the form token is valid ***/
elseif( $_POST['form_token'] != $_SESSION['form_token'])
{
    $message = 'Invalid form submission';
}
/*** check the username is the correct length ***/
elseif (strlen( $_POST['username']) > 20 || strlen($_POST['username']) < 4)
{
    $message = 'Incorrect Length for Username';
}
/*** check the password is the correct length ***/
elseif (strlen( $_POST['password']) > 20 || strlen($_POST['password']) < 4)
{
    $message = 'Incorrect Length for Password';
}
/*** check the username has only alpha numeric characters ***/
elseif (ctype_alnum($_POST['username']) != true)
{
    /*** if there is no match ***/
    $message = "Username must be alpha numeric";
}
/*** check the password has only alpha numeric characters ***/
elseif (ctype_alnum($_POST['password']) != true)
{
        /*** if there is no match ***/
        $message = "Password must be alpha numeric";
}
else
{
    /*** if we are here the data is valid and we can insert it into database ***/
    $firstname = filter_var($_POST['firstname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $lastname = filter_var($_POST['lastname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $username = filter_var($_POST['username'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $password = filter_var($_POST['password'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $emailid = filter_var($_POST['emailid'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $teamname = filter_var($_POST['teamname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $secret_question = filter_var($_POST['secret_question'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $secret_answer = filter_var($_POST['secret_answer'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    

    /*** now we can encrypt the password ***/
    $password = sha1( $password );
    
    /*** connect to database ***/
    /*** mysql hostname ***/
    $mysql_hostname = 'localhost';

    /*** mysql username ***/
    $mysql_username = 'root';

    /*** mysql password ***/
    $mysql_password = 'imagination';

    /*** database name ***/
    $mysql_dbname = 'adb project';

    try
    {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_dbname", $mysql_username, $mysql_password);
        /*** $message = a message saying we have connected ***/

        /*** set the error mode to excptions ***/
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        /*** prepare the insert ***/
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO users (firstname,lastname,username,password,emailid,teamname, secret_question,secret_answer ) VALUES (:firstname,:lastname,:username,:password, :emailid,:teamname,:secret_question,:secret_answer)");

        /*** bind the parameters ***/
        $stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $lastname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR, 40);
        $stmt->bindParam(':emailid', $emailid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':teamname', $teamname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':secret_question', $secret_question, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':secret_answer', $secret_answer, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        /*** execute the prepared statement ***/
        $stmt->execute();

        /*** unset the form token session variable ***/
        unset( $_SESSION['form_token'] );

        /*** if all is done, say thanks ***/
        $message = 'New user added';
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        /*** check if the username already exists ***/
        if( $e->getCode() == 23000)
        {
            $message = 'Username already exists';
        }
        else
        {
            /*** if we are here, something has gone wrong with the database ***/
            $message = 'We are unable to process your request. Please try again later"';
        }
    }
}
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<p><?php echo $message; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the "please enter form correctly" error? I'm unable to find it in your code.

Comment: @Babblo i am sorry, i have changed to " work for the love of god" out of frustration. Its the first string i store in the `$message ` variable

Comment: So it's working. What is the problem?

Comment: thats the message i am supposed to get when the form details are not sent. I cant think of a reason why that is the case. Check the `if isset ` statement at the very beginning of the  `useradd.php ` code

Comment: Oops, sorry.. I didn't see the ! symbol

Comment: `name="Password"` has a capital P but the isset test doesn't

Comment: omg!! thank your sir, thank you!! Now its down to the other error message, the ' Invalid form submission' which happens when the form token is invalid

Answer (score 1):

Could this be it?

In form, you have a capital 'P' on `name="Password"` but in useradd.php your isset() tests for $_POST["password"] (small p)

With these types of problems, I immediately try to find out exactly where the process is failing, so I'll usually stick in a bunch of `echo "got to here 1";` and `echo "got to here 2";` so that I know the script made it to *here* and no further.

Comment: yup that was the issue. I was able to edit that . Now im stuck in the second error message

Comment: First of all, you may not need that one *at this point*. Get it all working first (and I've never used a token to authenticate a form...) Anyway, this may be where the problem lies: `uniqid('auth', true)`.  The `uniqid()` function is not part of PHP, so it's part of this tutorial. Perhaps there's a typo in there? At any rate, if I were you I would disable/remove that elseif and come back to it later, if at all.

Comment: Basically, the first file creates a string called `form_token` and saves it both as a session variable (called form_token) and in a hidden field. When posted to useradd.php, it checks what it received from that hidden field against the session variable set a few seconds ago. Its up to you: is this critical to your exercise? I would delete immediately and come back to it if/when everything else is working... (and maybe not even then)

Comment: i thought the uniqid can be stored in the database as a userid, which can later be checked in cases where only a registered user can view some specific content

Comment: Usually, we make the first field of the database a "table-name" ID (eg. "uid" for users table, "pid" for products table, etc). I set it to be INT(11), auto-increment, PRIMARY key (i.e. index column - PRIMARY). **That** is the unique user_id. No need for the other one.

Comment: as of now that is the plan. i have a userid as the primary key and that is set as auto increment.

Comment: Then could you say that the other (uniqid) var is superfluous and unnecessary, since userid is already a unique ID?

Comment: if i use the code given in the tutorial, as it is, on the same database, i can insert the username and password(encrypted) into the database. However, when i try and store more information, it fails. I just cant get it to work.

Comment: Again, simplify your useradd.php script. Strip out all the isset tests, and just echo out the fields you received. Once you are sure you got all the fields, then add them to the DB one at a time until you are sure you did them all right. Remember to put echo 'here i am 01 (or 02 or 03...)' statements so you can immed find where you went wrong.

Comment: Right now i actually do not care what is superflous, if i can get this to work, ill b more than happy. Its confusing, cz if i use the code exactly the way it is on the website, with just username and password fields, i can store it in the same database. But when i edit it to suit my needs for the new form, to store the firstname, lastname and emailid, it just fails....

Comment: If the code you have above is what you're running it through, no wonder you cannot find the problem. It does a million things - which one is broken? Strip it down to the bare essentials just to see if that works, then re-build. (1) Receive $_POST vars and echo them back. (2) Do mysql_query() statements to insert the values into the DB one at a time: Do *one* $dbh, $stmt, $stmt->bindParam(), $stmt->execute -- for one field -- at a time.  Yes, it's a lot of testing work, but you would have been done hours ago if started when wrote question.

Comment: do you know about phpAcademy.org? Alex Garrett has numerous FREE video series to help ($pay only if wish to download videos or get source code - but well worth the LOW price). The one you should watch is called Registration & Login OOP.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined in your form name="Password" twice

Comment: that was for the "re enter password" field. i removed it and tried again. No luck

Comment: I know but you should use different names for fields in lowercase